# Relation between crystalline and perverse sheaves

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, perverse-sheaves, crystals

Take $X$ to be a smooth complex projective algebraic variety.  The Riemann-Hilbert correspondence gives an equivalence of categories between the category of perverse sheaves on $X$ and the category of holonomic D-modules on $X$.

Now Lurie, in the lecture "Notes on Crystals and Algebraic D-Modules" [(link)](http://www.math.harvard.edu/~gaitsgde/grad_2009/SeminarNotes/Nov17-19(Crystals).pdf), demonstrates that in the above setting the category of quasicoherent D-modules is equivalent to the category of crystals of quasicoherent sheaves, or equivalently quasicoherent sheaves on the crystalline site.  So the obvious inclusion of the D-module categories will give us perverse sheaves as a subcategory of crystalline sheaves.

Can I in general think of perverse sheaves as a subcategory of sheaves on the crystalline site?  None of the literature I have seen on perverse sheaves takes this point of view, so I am somewhat suspicious of it; is it written up anywhere?

Comment: There should be an equivalence of derived categories that do *not* respect the underlying abelian categories. I guess it is possible to develop the theory in a purely algebraic fashion, but as far as I know this is not written up anywhere.

Comment: I think the version of RH you're reffering to is the equivalence (in alg. closed char 0) between the abelian category of holonomic D modules **with regular singularities** and perverse sheaves.